# How to update row of data in SQLite3 database using user entry in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I would like to ask if it is possible to inherit Python variables/arrays into sqlite3, if not, is there any way how I can update a database via user entry, can't seem to find any way how to do it throughout the internet. Also, I'm not sure what to put after the WHERE keyword, I want to update a highlighted row of data inside the database using my application in Tkinter.

```
value = [firstname, firstname, lastname, gender, age, contact, address, district]
selected = resident_treeview.focus()
resident_treeview.item(selected, text="", values=value)

c.execute('''UPDATE Resident_Data SET firstname= value[0], lastname= value[1], gender= value[2], age= value[3], contact_number= value[4], address= value[5], district= value[6] WHERE ...??;''', value)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I tried using the f-string method but it says invalid syntax since I wrote it inside the `c.execute` function. I am expecting a method similar to inserting a variable into a string where {} can be found inside the double quotations but in sqlite3 syntax.

Comment: Normally a table has at least an unique column which is used in WHERE clause of an UPDATE statement if a particular row in the table need to be updated.  Also using those `value[x]` directly inside the UPDATE statement is not correct in your case.  It is better to provide the table definition of `Resident_Data` table.